# C# saveFileDialog open twice

Tags: c#, memorystream, savefiledialog

I have a datatable (dt) and a button to export the data to excel.

I'm using ClosedXML to do the job done.

But, when I click on export button, I got first saveFileDialog and then after I click OK, I got a second saveFileDialog. After this, the file is exported correctly.

So, the code...

This is the main code for the button export action. I'm using the saveFileDIalog to allow user choose the save file directory.

```
private void exportarToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(saveFileDialog.FileName);
            SaveToExcel(dt, fileInfo);
        }
    }
```

Then, the methods

```
public static void SaveToExcel(System.Data.DataTable dt, FileInfo outputFile)
    {
        XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
        var worksheet = wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "ResultTable");

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = GetStream(wb))
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes(outputFile.FullName, memoryStream.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

And the MemoryStream

```
public static MemoryStream GetStream(XLWorkbook excelWorkbook)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            excelWorkbook.SaveAs(stream, new SaveOptions { EvaluateFormulasBeforeSaving = false, GenerateCalculationChain = false, ValidatePackage = false,  });
            return stream;
        }
    }
```

Can please someone help me see why I'm getting 2 saveFileDialog?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you debugged this? How sure are you that the event is not being triggered twice? Note that you won't see two files if this is the case, since once will overwrite the others. The dialog is the only _noticeable_ effect from triggering the effect more than once.

Comment: It's also weird to read the filename **before** showing the dialog to the user. Is the user unable to specify a filename? Because if they are able to, then they may have changed the filename in the dialog.

Comment: In SaveToExcel function, why are you calling GetStream twice ?

Comment: Also.. why are you disposing the `MemoryStream` when you're returning it? You should dispose it in the function that uses it (like you're doing).

Comment: The standard reason is accidentally subscribing the Click event twice.

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem; I added some comments:

```
private void exportarToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filename = saveFileDialog.FileName; // what is this for? I would remove it.
    if(saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // problem in the following line, explained below
        string path = Path.GetFullPath(filename);
        // you should be picking the saveFileDialog.FileName at this point  to get
        // the user selection, not the filename variable you got before;
        // moreover, the saveFileDialog.FileName is already a full path, no need to
        // call the Path.GetFullPath method
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
        SaveToExcel(dt, fileInfo);
    }
}
```

Edit: And other problems are reported in other users' comments (bad MemoryStream management)

Comment: In the first savefileDialog popup, the file is saved. In the second popup, the file is overriten. So, why am I getting 2 popups? I changed my code on first post accordingly to your answers.

Comment: Then maybe, as @Hans Passant has noticed, you may have registered the exportarToolStripMenuItem_Click event handler twice. It happens; maybe you registered it in the .designer code via Visual Studio and then re-added it in your code. Check that.

Comment: Yep... Forgot this on Form Constructor... exportarToolStripMenuItem.Click += new EventHandler(this.exportarToolStripMenuItem_Click); Now only one popup is shown. Thank you all!

Comment: Last, let me add: some try-catch would be advisable. If the user selects an existing file, which he may have opened in Excel, you could get an access denied exception. It would be a pity that your program crashes. Better put the code in the event handler into a try-catch block and provide a MessageBox alert in case of any exception.